# Comic where some angelic women fights against some terrorist/insurgents?

Tags: story-identification, comics

Okay, so I remember reading this comic (around 2002) where there was this sort of a powerful psychic or angel-like blonde haired women. She was killing people who looked like some sort of insurgents or terrorists in some war-torn city somewhere in the near East. I think it was at night or something. I am not sure since the sky was filled with black smoke and the background was colored red. This part was somewhere near the end, I think.

The blond haired women had somewhat long hair, and I think one side of her hair (a small part of it) was kinda like rope-braided in style. She attacks or kills people with the fingernails of her left hand by turning them into claws. Her other power is that she can kill and mutilate people with strands of her hair. The hair strands are able to penetrate bricks, walls, and even steel. She can also extend them for range. Whenever she uses those two powers there is this some sort angelic energy wings manifesting behind her. They fade away when she doesn't use those powers. The terrorist-like people were armed with, I think, AK-47s, other rifles, rocket launchers, and other guns.

I think she ends up killing something like all the terrorists and she continues to move to her objective. If I remember correctly, I think she is ordered to kill everyone in that city, that place being like the main base of the terrorist faction. I think she is part of some kind of an elite special counter-insurgency unit known as "Hunters", or something like that. I think the unit compromised of other psychics like her, but she was the strongest one out of all of them, or the one with the highest potential, or something like that.

Anyway, I think she eventually reaches close to an airfield, where I think the remaining terrorist faction was evacuating the normal people like kids, women, elderly people and other non-combatants. Some of the terrorists move in to intercept her. I think the terrorists' plan was that they were not only trying to stall enough time for the evacuation but they were also stalling for time until two other psychics arrived to actually fight her. I think they knew that, even if they somehow managed to evacuate the evacuees, the blonde-haired girl would just destroy their aircraft in flight. Also, I think, the two psychics were part of the special counter-insurgency unit. But I think they realize what's really going on, so they decide to assist the Terrorist faction.

Unfortunately, they weren't able to stall her from entering the airbase for long enough. She ends up killing almost all evacuees and the airships. But I think the main character, who is also a terrorist, and a few other last remaining terrorists, intervene to keep her from destroying the last two air crafts. But, within a minute, she manages to kill all of them except for the main character, who barely just survives. But just as she is about to kill him with her hair, her powers don't seem to work. Just then two psychics inform the main character telepathically that they will be there in another ten minutes. It is revealed that her powers don't seem to work because the ability of one of the psychics is to inactivate anyone's psychic power who is within 2 miles of him.

This gives a small chance for the main character to stall for ten more minutes. However, it turns out that while the blond woman's hair and claw powers seems to be inactive, she still has retained her super reflexes, body toughness, and strength. Soon, the main character realizes that fighting even for a minute seems way too long. None of his punches seems to land due to her superior
reflexes. She even breaks the bones on his right hand and both his legs. But he still manages to get up and stand in her way due to his resolve of protecting his younger brother and sister who are on the last two surviving planes, which are preparing to take off. However, she picks him by the neck and begins choking him. It is revealed that he had two grenades with the pins removed. As a result he dies, but the blond psychic girl doesn't, although she is still somewhat wounded.

I don't remember what exactly happens after that. I think the last two aircraft manage to escape thanks to the two psychics who arrive to intervene against the blond  psychic girl. I think they don't manage to kill her, and they get killed by her. I think the comic ends with the message of finding hope by yourself in a closed society.

Another interesting thing to note is that only the main character had that balaclava terrorist mask. His character design kinda looks like one of the terrorist models from the original *Counter-strike* game, reference: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPxll.png). The other terrorists either didn't cover their face or they had something like [tagelmust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagelmust) on. He is the only one whose face is never revealed, although they show his face when he was younger. When he was young, he and other kids with a similar background to his were bullied in school, looked down upon, and were considered the bottom of society, the cause being the results of massive globalization by the start of 20th century. It in fact became a norm in the society to classify people by their wealth, grades and their stature.

Comment: That's quite the description...

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Although this description is already nicely detailed, these might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)